# Could you save this proof? (of Wedderburn's Little Theorem)

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to prove **Wedderburn's Little Theorem**. It is very famous and important, and is stated as below:

**Every finite division ring is a field**.
Consider the division ring generated by a subgroup:

Let $\textbf{D}$ be a finite division ring, H be a subgroup of $\textbf{$D^{*}$}$ and $\textbf{$F_H$:={$h_i$$\in$H$\mid$$\sum$$h_i$}}$. It is clear that $\textbf{$F_H$}$ is a finite division ring since it is in fact a group ring and its elements have finite order. If H is a commutative group and $\textbf{$F_H$}$ has to be $\textbf{D}$ but not any proper subdivision ring of $\textbf{D}$, then we can claim that $\textbf{D}$ is commutative.

My idea is to consider its p-group. Since $\mid \textbf{D} \mid$=$p^n$, where p is a prime number, the order of subdivision ring of $\textbf{D}$ must be $q^m$,$m \mid n$. Now consider all numbers in the form: $\textbf{$\frac{q^n-1}{q^m-1}$}$, m $<$ n and $m \mid n$. Those kinds of numbers can not be coprime and they have a non-trivial common divisor: prime p$\neq$q (according to Bezout's theorem). For example, let q=2 and n=4. If m $<$ n and $m \mid n$,m=1 or 2,$\frac{2^4-1}{2^2-1}=5$, $\frac{2^4-1}{2^1-1}$=15, they have common divisor p=5. So there is a p subgroup $\textbf{P}$ of $\textbf{$D^{*}$}$, the finite division ring generated by P (denoted as $\textbf{$F_P$}$) must coincide with $\textbf{D}$.

But I fail to show that $\textbf{P}$ is commutative. According to $\textbf{Sylow's Theorem}$,$\textbf{P}$ must be contained in a Sylow group of $\textbf{$D^{*}$}$. So the only thing we remain to do is to show that:

**Every Sylow group of $D^{*}$ is commutative, without using Wedderburn's Little Theorem**.

Could you help me?

Comment: I know of three more or less well known proofs of this theorem, none of which is short or too simple: Witt's, Zassenhaus' and Herstein's. I even have a paper with these proofs. Now, is the above an idea of yours or are you trying to follow some proof?

Comment: I have seen these 3 proofs,and I know there are many proofs of this theorem.I guarantee that the idea is from me but i don't know how to carry it on.

Comment: Neither I can see right now how to carry on, yet I can already ask: what if all the Sylow subgroups of $\;D^*\;$ are abelian? How would this lead you already to deduce $\;D\;$ is commutative?

Comment: Let me list a concrete example:Division ring $\textbf{D}$ of order $2^4$.then $\mid D^{*} \mid$ is 15.consider the Sylow 5-subgroup G(It must exist!),and as talked above,it can generate $\textbf{$F_G$}$,a subdivision ring of $\textbf{D}$.It must be $\textbf{D}$ itself,for It must be a subdivision ring of D,bit it can not be of order $2^2=4$ and $2^1$=2.Now I have already proved that there exists a prime number p and a p-subgroup $\textbf{P}$,such that $\textbf{$F_P$}$ must be D itself.The way to find p is to find a common prime divisor of $\frac{q^n-1}{q^m-1}$,$n<m$,n$\mid$m.

Comment: Well,go on.By Bezout's theorem, $\frac{q^n-1}{q^m-1}$,$m<n$,n$\mid$m,they can not be coprime,so we can always find that p.The way to construct $\textbf{P}$ by p is:Consider $\textbf{MAX}$:=$ord_{p}{(q^m-1)}$,$m<n$,m $\mid$ n.then $ord_{p}{q^n-1}$$>$$\textbf{MAX}$,because p is a common divisor of $\frac{(q^n-1)}{(q^m-1)}$,$m<n$,n$\mid$m.then we can get a number:$\textbf{NUM:=}$ $p^{ord_{p}{(q^n-1)}}$.By sylow's theorem,a group of order  $\textbf{NUM}$ must exist,and it can generate a division ring coinciding with $\textbf{D}$,since for any $m \mid n$,$m<n$,$ord_{p}{(q^m-1)}<ord_{p}{(q^n-1)}$.

Comment: $\textbf{Correction of my second comment.}$The way to find p is to find a common prime divisor of $\frac{q^n-1}{q^m-1}$,$m<n$,$m \mid n$.

Comment: @Muse_China You can use `**[TEXT]**` for boldface texts. You should reserve the `\mathbf` command for boldface letters or text inside equations. It also makes the loading of the page clumsier, so it is better to avoid using it unless really necessary.